# How to average two points in nalgebra?

Tags: rust, linear-algebra, nalgebra

I have a triangle ABC, and I want to generate triangle DEF.

Triangle DEF is created using the centre of all edges of ABC. Nalgebra doesn't seem to allow me to do add points together, only vectors.

```rust
use nalgebra::Point2;

fn get_def(a: Point2<f32>, b: Point2<f32>, c: Point2<f32>) -> [Point2<f32>; 3] {
    let d = (a + b) / 2.0; // error
    let e = (b + c) / 2.0; // error
    let f = (c + a) / 2.0; // error

    [d, e, f]
}
```

[image: Triangles ABC and DEF].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nalgebra has a function specifically for this, [nalgebra::center](https://nalgebra.org/rustdoc/nalgebra/fn.center.html).

```rust
use nalgebra::{Point2, center};

fn get_def(a: Point2<f32>, b: Point2<f32>, c: Point2<f32>) -> [Point2<f32>; 3] {
    let d = center(&a, &b);
    let e = center(&b, &c);
    let f = center(&c, &a;

    [d, e, f]
}
```